# no suitable method for sort error

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Collection;

public class ClearlyAnArrayList
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer>ints=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int num=kb.nextInt();
            while(num!=-1){
            ints.add(num);
            }
    sortPrint(ints);
}

    public static void sortPrint(Collection<Integer>ints){
        Collections.sort(ints);
        for(Integer i:ints){
        System.out.printf("%d\n",i);
        }
}
}
```

> This is the code I'm compiling with blueJ When I compile it I get a
>   lengthy error which starts off "`no suitable method for
>   sort(java.util.Collection<java.lang.Integer>)`" and then goes on to
>   say more stuff I don't understand.

The solution to this was that I was using a List which is not a collection and `Collections.sort()` expects a List

> Also is there a better way than singular `import` statements for all
>   my utils?

The solution given was

```
import java.util.*;
```

Comment: I'd revise this question before people start down-voting it. State what the problem is and what you tried to fix it.

Comment: Include the exact error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) expects a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and not [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), so change your `sortPrint` method
From

```
Collection<Integer>ints
```

To

```
List<Integer> ints
```

Offtopic:

Instead of working directly on concrete classes [program to an interface](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html).

Prefer

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Over

```
ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Yes, please read the link associated with program to an interface in my answer for details

Answer (score 2):

what about just doing this:

```
public static void sortPrint(List<Integer> ints){
    Collections.sort(ints);
    for(Integer i:ints){
    System.out.printf("%d\n",i);
    }
```

`Collections.sort()` is only for `List`

Answer (score 0):

For your import

```
import java.util.*;
```

The the sort method sort a List, not a collection, so change you declaration to :

```
public static void sortPrint(List<Integer> ints)
```

You can also have a collection that sort itself during insertion, your program become :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
        TreeSet<Integer>ints=new TreeSet<Integer>();
        int num=kb.nextInt();
        while(num!=-1){
            ints.add(num);
        }
        //already sorted
    }
```

Warning, in a Set (and so in a TreeSet) you cannot have the same element twice

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentations (or try to Ctrl + Space for information).

`java.until.Collections` documentation: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

This class only supports `Collections.sort(list)` and `Collections.sort(list,comparator)`
, so you can not sort the `Collection`. Try `List` instead